# API-Gateway with Spring boot Eureka is not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, api-gateway

I have a simple Product project where I want to create multiple instances of the Product microservice and API-Gateway that will register to Eureka server.

I have the following eureka server configurations:

[image]

application.properties:

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

I have the following application.properties for the API-Gateway microservice:
[image]

```
spring.application.name=api-gateway
server.port=8082
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true
```

I have the following application.properties for the Product microservice

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
spring.application.name=product-service
server.port=0
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${instanceId:${random.value}}
```

I have created the RestController for the /products mapping

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
@Slf4j
public class ProductController {

    private final CommandGateway commandGateway;

    public ProductController(CommandGateway commandGateway) {
        this.commandGateway = commandGateway;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createProduct(@RequestBody CreateProductDTO createProductDTO) {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I start the applications and check the localhost:8761, I notice that the host of the gateway microservice is host.docker.internal
[image]

When I send the request from Postman application I receive the following response:

[image]

Comment: Share your API Gateway routes code.